# How to resize an imageView to a certain size in pixels with java? (In android studio)

Tags: java, android

How can I change the size of the imageView through code without cropping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize as you wish with the functions below.

```
public void setWidth(View view, Integer width){
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}

public void setHeight(View view, Integer height){
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have several options there. you could just change width and height of ImageView and it would be resized. if effect isnt satisfying, you could play with scaleType and adjustViewBounds, however simplest workaround would be to just change scaleX and scaleY of ImageView.